# With doxygen, can you jump to a member function using just the function name?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Have a (non-existing) class Example with member function `initialize_impl`.
I have to refer to it many many times in the documentation. I could use `@link Example::initialize_impl initialize_impl @endlink` as that would not show the `Example::` part but would still jump to the top of the documentation for `initialize_impl`.

Is there is a way to only have to write `initialize_impl`, or at most `@ref initialize_impl` and still do the same thing?

I tried adding an `@anchor`, but that doesn't work: the anchor is added much to far down (even after the @brief description, and certainly not at the very top like the @link would).

What I really need thus is a way to tell doxygen, whenever I type this or that keyword do the same thing as `@link Example::keyword keyword @endlink`.

Is this possible?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the initialize_impl  or \ref initialize_imp or #initialize_imp should work or otherwise try to place EXAMPLE:: in front of it. In case it does not work as you expect please post some code and the exact results you would like to have and what you a actually get.

Comment: @albert That can't work, since there are more classes with a initialize_impl member function. Just putting \ref in front of it or a # results in a link with href="" (empty link in the html code). Putting Example:: in front of it works, but prints the Example:: part too.

Comment: Revisiting. Please add a complete example as I don't get it.